# Possible to view file outline in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Can you view a file's outline in Xcode for programming, similar to the [Outline View](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_outline_view.htm) in Eclipse? See below for example:

**Target (Eclipse Ref)**

[image]

is this possible in Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a code file in Xcode there is a file path between the text area containing your code and the toolbar:

[image: Xcode Toolbar]

You can see the scope in which the cursor is currently in (or "No Selection" if the cursor is at top level).

If you click on that you get an outline for the current file:

[image: Xcode File Outline]

Comment: My goodness, Palle thank you. After research this is found at "View->Standard Editor->Show Document Items" and is accessed with hotkey 'Ctrl+6'. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An outline such as the one in Eclipse is the Symbol Navigator (⌘3).
It is sorted and can be filtered. Don't expect the full features of Eclipse though.

[image: Symbol Navigator]